# How do I populate a 2d array with hashmaps without double for loop

Tags: java, performance, multidimensional-array, hashmap

Say I create a 2d array of hashmaps as such:

```
Map<String,String>[][] matrix = new Map[5][10];
```

Is there a way I can populate each entry in this matrix with empty hashmaps without doing the standard double for loop?

Comment: why are you mixing arrays with maps?  I could understand if you wanted a List of Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner using the [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class:

```
Arrays.stream(matrix).forEach(row -> Arrays.setAll(row, i -> new HashMap<>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    matrix[i / 10][i % 10] = new HashMap<>();
}
```

But why?

Answer (score 0):

Let's not forget another option: array initializer:

```
Map<String, String>[][] = new Map[][] {
    {new HashMap<>(), ... 8 more like that..., new HashMap<>()},
       // 3 more lines like the one above... 
    {new HashMap<>(), ..., new HashMap<>() }
};
```

That's 50 `new HashMap<>()`s in total. Double `for` loop not looking so bad now, eh?